# Want to attach my list to database and make it dynamic in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to attach my this list to database and grab images from there.. I am not sure about how many images will be there. I have a folder named clients with images and a database of sql from where i grab the image path and want to put it within li.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="list_carousel">
                    <ul id="foo0">
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-01.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-02.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-03.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-04.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-05.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-01.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-02.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-03.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-04.png" alt="" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/logo-05.png" alt="" /></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add question and show code that you have problem with...

Comment: basically i have no idea how to get in dynamic

Comment: Get a book or a tutorial on aspx/c# and controls. Quickstart here are some controls you can use in webforms http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to get the images path from the database, create a place holer in your aspx page e.g.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ImagesPlaceHolder">
</asp:Label>
```

In code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("<div class=\"list_carousel\">");
   sb.Append("<ul id=\"foo0\">");

   List<string> images = GetImagesPathsFromDB();

   foreach(string path in images)
   {
       sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", path);
   }

   sb.Append("</ul>");
   sb.Append("<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>");
   sb.Append("</div>");

   ImagesPlaceHolder.Text = sb.ToString();  //or ImagesPlaceHolder.InnertHTML = sb.ToString();
}
```